# How does Active Record save initialize the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

When you save a model, there are some model attributes that get their value from the database like:

1. primary key
2. column defaults set at the mysql level

When you insert a record (save), does it actually make 2 calls under the covers i.e Insert and then Select ?

Comment: You can look at your server logs to see what happens.  I just tried a simple user create with Postgres, and it uses a single `INSERT` with a `RETURNING` clause to return the new id: `SQL (11.9ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("username", "password_digest", "session_token", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"`

Comment: @dwenzel but what if the table has defaults set at the postgresl level?

Comment: hmm... I just tried creating a new object with defaults, and it did NOT do a query for the defaults after creating; again, just a `RETURNING` clause with the id.  But Rails did return the default values.  I'm not sure how Rails knows these values; maybe from looking at the schema in the code?  
I'll leave it to the more experienced folks here to answer that one.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord doesn't make a query after the save to get that information. My understanding of `ActiveRecord` is that it maintains internally a lot of information about the database structure, for example the names and types of all the columns, so that it can generate the corresponding methods in the models. Also it would know what the default value is so it can set that in the model at the same time as the db sets it.

This is not completely DRY and would cause lots of problems if you bypass `ActiveRecord` to restructure the database, but the savings in overhead with less database touches is well worth it.